# Python error message shown multiple times- Visual Studio Code insiders

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Python (jupyter notebook file) in Visual Code Insiders. When I have an error, it is being shown three times.  It's really that second error message that is particularly annoying because sometimes it runs on multiple lines it and takes a while to scroll past. I would like it to only show that third error message (which is being displayed in the traditional format). How would I disable the first two error messages?

[image]